# Azure: How to call a WebRole method from a controller of my MVC implementation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-worker-roles, azure-web-roles

I'm working on a MVC webapp using Azure with ASP.Net MVC 2 C#. I have a worker role from where I interact with a queue reading messages with images. I initialize the queue in my WebRole, and I want to call a method to enqueue elements from my controller. I don't know how to do this call.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the queue is straightforward:

```
var queueClient = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("mystorage").CreateCloudQueueClient();
var myQueue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("myqueue");
string myMessageContent = "Some formatted queue message"; // this could be bytes as well
var myQueueMessage = new CloudQueueMessage(myMessageContent);
myQueue.AddMessage(myQueueMessage);
```

One bit of advice: When *creating* the queue, do it in your role's OnStart(), not in the Run(). This way, it'll be created before your web app ever shows up in the Azure load balancer.